# How do I stack elements inside a div on both left and right?

Tags: css

I have my elements inside a div like this:

```
<div>
    <p class="left"> left side element 1 </p>
    <p class="right"> right side element 1 </p>
    <p class="left"> left side element 2 </p>
    <p class="left"> left side element 3 </p>
    <p class="right"> right side element 2 </p>
</div>
```

How can I make them stack left and right accordingly to their classes?
*Note: The HTML is generated from server side.*

Expected output:

```
[ left side element 1 ]     [ right side element 1 ]
[ left side element 2 ]     [ right side element 2 ]
[ left side element 3 ]
```

I have tried using float first, they were not stacking on the others. Then tried absolute positioning for the children relatively to their parents but it's giving me pain to write each elements `left` `right` and `top` `bottom` values. Is their an easy way so that I can achieve the result?

Comment: on left, try clear:left, and on right, try clear:right

Comment: Are you only looking for plain CSS solutions?

Comment: @Pangloss yes, CSS only.

Comment: Does all `<p>` have the same width and height?

Comment: No, they are all different. @Pangloss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this design using the flex property *order* and a little trick with a pseudo element on the container, to force a wrap on the right elements

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container::before {
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block; /* needed only by IE */
    order: 150;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.left {
    order: 100;
}

.right {
    order: 200;
}

p {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="left"> left side element 1 </p>
    <p class="right"> right side element 1 </p>
    <p class="left"> left side element 2 </p>
    <p class="left"> left side element 3 </p>
    <p class="right"> right side element 2 </p>
</div>
```

Of course, the red pseudo element shouldn't be visible in production code. I made it visible only for demo purposes.

The key issue here is that the pseudo element can have an order property set (something that didn't happen in older browsers)

Comment: Awesome! I was also tried to achieve this with flex. But didn't know the other flex properties like direction, basis and wrap. Learned some new things, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following (***disclaimer:*** not a real solution just a trick if your requirements meet certain criteria)

```css
div{position:relative;}
.left, .right{position:absolute;outline:1px solid #ccc;top:0;}
.left{left:0;}
.right{right:0;color:red;}

.left ~ .left{top:40px;}
.left ~ .left ~ .left{top:80px;}
.left ~ .left ~ .left ~ .left{top:120px;}
.left ~ .left ~ .left ~ .left ~ .left{top:160px;}
.left ~ .left ~ .left ~ .left ~ .left ~ .left{top:200px;}


.right ~ .right{top:40px;}
.right ~ .right ~ .left{top:80px;}
.right ~ .right ~ .right ~ .right{top:120px;}
.right ~ .right ~ .right ~ .right ~ .right{top:160px;}
.right ~ .right ~ .right ~ .right ~ .right ~ .right{top:200px;}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="left"> left side element 1 </p>
    <p class="right"> right side element 1 </p>
    <p class="left"> left side element 2 </p>
    <p class="left"> left side element 3 </p>
    <p class="right"> right side element 2 </p>
</div>
```

But it will only work (*in this example*) for up to 6 `.left` and 6 `.right` elements. Also it assumes that `40px` is enough to fit each box..

---

For a real solution you will have to either change the html (server side) or do the grouping with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add div elements inside the outer div ?

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left"><p class="left"> left side element 1 </p></div>
  <div style="float:right"><p class="right"> right side element 1 </p></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div style="float:left"><p class="left"> left side element 2 </p></div>
  <div style="float:right"><p class="right"> right side element 2 </p></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

- You gotta make sure the width of the divs with the float style is large enough or the elements might stack below each other.

Comment: No, as the HTML is generating from server side.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I think the proper answer would be to **change whatever code/template is generating the server-side** code to include container `div` elements.

If this is impossible than you could use javascript to do this on the fly, **however I personally would not recommend this and use it only as a very last resort.**

Something like this would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/wmhbeo0v/

but it can become a nightmare for other developers to maintain so hopefully you can use the HTML element structure as a guide for changing the server-side scripts instead.

---

You could use the `clear` CSS rule to align the elements left and right, though I'm not sure if the gap under 'right side element 1' is an issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/wg3qothr/

```
.left{
  float:left;
  clear:left;
}
.right{
  float:right;
  clear:right;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's an issue. They are not truly stacking then.

Comment: @AnisKhan - I've updated my answer based on your response.

Comment: @AnisKhan - I've also updated the fiddle with neater code.